# Determine if git merge/pull made any changes in Windowsbatch file

Tags: git

How do I use git.exe in a Windows batch file to pull changes and determine whether any changes were made to my working copy? Both pull and merge seem to return exit code 0 for "success", whether changes were made or not.

I've done this by redirecting stdout to a temporary file and comparing it with `FC` to a file containing "Already up to date." This works, but seems like a big hack. Is there a better way?

This is for a script that pulls remote changes, does a build, runs unit tests and then pushes. Just before the push I want to check if anyone else has pushed changes while my script was running and, if so, do the build and run the tests again.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use git.exe in a Windows batch file to pull changes and determine whether any changes were made to my working copy

You can do this:

```
# update the local repo with changes from the remote
git fetch --all -prune

# check to see if there is a difference between your local branch and the remote branch

git log <branch>...origin/<branch>
```

If you see any changes you know that you are not up to date

---

Another way:

```
# update the local repo
git fetch --all --prune

# compare the 2 commits to see if there are any new commits
# the commands will return SHA-1 simply compare them
git rev-parse origin/dev
git rev-parse dev
```

Comment: Thanks, but this requires the names of the local and remote branches, which my script doesn't have. (I can still do `git pull` and `git push origin HEAD` just fine without knowing the branch names.) I think for the local branch I can use `git rev-parse HEAD`, but for the remote branch `git rev-parse origin` gives the wrong result.